# Failed to resolve appcompat-v7:15.+ in Android studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed android studio 1.4 on MAC 10.10.3 successfully. Now when I try to for demo app. development I see two errors in the main IDE, both of them are marked with arrow in the below figure[image]

I clicked on the links (near the bottom arrow), it did some installations, but again errors were there. Now when I click on the links again it shows

[image]

Apart from this I followed other answers on stackoverflow, but with no success. Can anyone guess what can be the possible reason for both of these problems

Comment: post your gradle file.

Comment: can you open you sdk manager and see what version of Android Support Repository is installed ? Try to re-install/update from Sdk Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

You should use the latest `AppCompat` library.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Change dependencies on your `build.gradle` your Support library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, and after looking myself, I managed to resolve the error without accumulating any more errors by entering:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
```

My thinking is that it'll now just check for versions 7:20 and above.
Hope that helps.